# Serve static files using routes in express.js

Tags: javascript, express

I have a bunch of html files that I want to serve as static files. However, I need the routes to not have any .html in it.

When the route is 
example.com/about
it should serve about.html

The research I did on serving static files seems to suggest that it is not entirely possible. Is that right, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to serve your static file using the router

```
app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
    res.render('about.html');
});
```

Before that you should setup a middleware for the html rendering engine

Or if you have a lot of static files, you could use a middleware to do it for you

https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-urls

Answer (score 0):

You can create a short little piece of middleware that will process whichever preset names you configure it for.  Anything not in that list will go to your normal routes:

```
// create static file lookup table for the desired names
var staticFiles = ["about", "index", "home"].reduce(function(obj, item) {
    obj["/" + item] = true;
    return obj;
}, {});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // if the path is found in the lookup table, then
    // add ".html" onto the end and get that file from the base directory
    // of you could use any source directory for those files
    if (staticFiles[req.path]) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, req.path + ".html"));
        return;
    }
    next();
});
```

Note: this very carefully only serves specific files so nobody can go snooping around in your file system with other types of URLs.

---

Here's an example where the files are served from a subdirectory below our base directory named "html":

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (staticFiles[req.path]) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "html", req.path + ".html"));
        return;
    }
    next();
});
```

---

In node v0.12+, you can use the `Set` object for your list of static routes like this:

```
var staticFiles = new Set(["/about", "/index", "/home"]);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (staticFiles.has(req.path)) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "html", req.path + ".html"));
        return;
    }
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of static pages, the ideal way would be to put them up in a single route, lets call it `static.js`. It can be something like,

```
module.exports = function () {
var router = require('express').Router();

var pages = {
    'about-us': 'path/to/about-us',
    'contact-us': 'path/to/contact-us'
};

router.get('/:page', function (req, res, next) {
    if (! pages[req.params.page]) {
        return next();
    }

    res.render(pages[req.params.page]);
});

return router;
};
```

Attach this route to the app, `app.use(require('./static')());` and you are good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'xyz')));
```

where xyz is the folder you are trying to make available as static. The folder name is relative to the application root.

Comment: this will not work, as it points the route as about instead of about.html

Comment: Time, is correct.  You should try some other middleware like this for example.  https://github.com/divshot/clean-urls